# Photoshop: color profiles for web?

Tags: photoshop, color-profile

**color settings --> working space**

[Usability post](http://www.usabilitypost.com/2008/07/30/photoshop-color-profiles-for-web-images/) tells us

> at the “Working Spaces” section and select the sRGB IEC61966-2.1 profile

[Smashing magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/12/setting-up-photoshop-for-web-app-and-iphone-development/) tells us to

> set the working space for RGB to Monitor RGB.

[http://viget.com/](http://viget.com/inspire/the-mysterious-save-for-web-color-shift) also recommends

> changing the top drop-down to Monitor Color.

What should we use?

**Second part of the question: saving for web:**
Should we always uncheck the 'Convert to sRGB'? There is also contradictory tutorials on this one.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Web images should be saved whithout any addition data. No color profiles. Many browsers read color profiles of how they are want.
sRGB IEC61966-2.1 or Monitor RGB is the same profile in color settings.
You doesnt need to check convert to rgb. Try to check but you will nothing to see changes if you work in sRGB colors already.